# Client Authentication failure for Azure non-Global Administrator

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have configured my android application to use Microsoft identity client. I am able to sign in successfully on the android application with my Microsoft outlook social login account which is a member of the Global Administrator in Azure AD. However, any other account is unable to go past the "Let this app access your info" login process after selecting the 'Yes' option

Comment: What is the error message after "any other account selects the 'Yes' option"?

Comment: there is no error message. When one clicks 'Yes' it just loops back to the same prompt. I have managed to get round the issue by changing the scope value from 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' to 'openid'. Initially the system could not generate a valid access token when using 'openid' and had to change. It could have been identified by Microsoft and fixed. I will post this as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Changed the scope value from 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' to 'openid' as a workaround